# how to insert <p> tags where there is a line break

Tags: html

How can I automatically insert `<p>` tags into a block of text?

I want to turn this:

```
"Sed quis dignissim sem. Sed porttitor metus non ligula tempus at pellentesque magna ultrices.

Pellentesque fermentum dignissim lacus, eget consectetur ipsum dictum a. Sed fermentum velit vitae magna scelerisque blandit. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum id tellus quis velit dictum lacinia."
```

into this:

```
"<p>Sed quis dignissim sem. Sed porttitor metus non ligula tempus at pellentesque magna ultrices.

<p>Pellentesque fermentum dignissim lacus, eget consectetur ipsum dictum a. Sed fermentum velit vitae magna scelerisque blandit. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum id tellus quis velit dictum lacinia."
```

Comment: In what language?  Also, you should close your tags.

Comment: How do you mean automatically? Client- or server side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is your text coming from?

You'll need to use either Javascript or a server language (PHP?) to do this.

In most languages something like this will do it though:

```
var string = "lakjdsf lkjafsd jkladfsjlk adfslk jafsl kadfslk jadfsl kdjk l jklaj kladfsj kladfsj kl"
var html = string.replace(/\n/g, "<br>")
```

PHP has a built-in function that does this called [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php):

```
<?php echo nl2br("foo isn't\n bar"); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want html tags in your output, you must encode them.  so to show a <p> tag (like I just did) you should type in &lt;p&gt;

Comment: if this is indeed what you're asking for, here's one place the entities are listed: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

Comment: i'm thinking i took the question a bit too literally :-)